# How can I see what the currently deployed version of Solana is?

Tags: version

I can view the latest releases [on github](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/releases), but this doesn't tell me what the current version on mainnet is. I'm aware I can find out what the current major version is by just googling, but if I want to find out if the current version is 1.17.1 or 1.17.2 for example this isn't so easy. How can I find this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, I can use the solana-cli for this:

`solana cluster-version`

Answer (score 1):

You can also find out the API version of a given RPC by making a JSON-RPC request to it

eg

```
$ curl https://api.devnet.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "id":1,
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "method":"getLatestBlockhash",
    "params":[]
  }
' | grep apiVersion
```

Will currently include `{"apiVersion":"1.17.17","slot":276020945}` in the output

Note that not all RPC methods include this context in the response, but many do. You can see the shape of the output of all RPC methods here: https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http

Answer (score 0):

Since the validators are all independent and can run whatever version they wish, it's also useful to see what versions the whole cluster is using by running `solana validators`, ie:

```
$ solana validators -um
... truncating ...
Stake By Version:
1.18.1  -    1 current validators ( 0.01%)
1.18.0  -    4 current validators ( 0.05%)
1.17.19 -    1 current validators ( 0.01%)
1.17.18 -  192 current validators (14.11%)   3 delinquent validators ( 0.02%)
1.17.17 -  463 current validators (19.00%)  17 delinquent validators ( 0.12%)
1.17.16 - 1082 current validators (64.42%)  15 delinquent validators ( 0.27%)
1.17.15 -    3 current validators ( 0.07%)
1.17.14 -    1 current validators ( 0.06%)
1.17.12 -    0 current validators ( 0.00%)   1 delinquent validators ( 0.00%)
1.17.7  -    1 current validators ( 0.00%)   1 delinquent validators ( 0.00%)
1.16.27 -    2 current validators ( 0.41%)
1.16.26 -    7 current validators ( 0.26%)   5 delinquent validators ( 0.01%)
1.16.25 -    1 current validators ( 0.00%)
1.16.24 -    3 current validators ( 1.01%)
1.16.23 -    2 current validators ( 0.09%)
1.16.20 -    1 current validators ( 0.01%)
1.16.18 -    3 current validators ( 0.01%)
unknown -    1 current validators ( 0.01%) 227 delinquent validators ( 0.02%)
```